# Light switch sizzled

Tags: electrical, switch, light

I had maintenance turn off my breaker and fix the pull tab on my ceiling fan. Then turned it back on... Few minutes later.... I turned on a light switch and it made a sizzling noice! Maintenance came back and flicked it off and on about 20 times and said it was fine and could have been a power surge! Is that true or should it get replaced??? Also i might fix myself..... But the wires are confusing.... What would happen if I get them mixed up?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If you don't feel comfortable working with electricity, then you should probably listen to your instincts; it could kill you. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Good for you. Asking questions before you dismantle everything and get into trouble.  As @Harper mentioned, take pictures before doing anything.  If the experts here (not me) know where the wires were, they can tell you where they should go. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Shoot photos of the wiring and let us walk you through it.

The usual place people get derailed is in 3-way switches; they count on the screw positions or wire colors meaning anything at all.  The screw positions vary on every switch, and the colors are *worse than random* in 3-ways. I even recommend you mark the *travelers* with yellow tape; doing so makes things easy.

Even on a 2-way you sometimes see more than 2 non-ground wires; almost always two always-hot wires  and the installer just used the switch terminals as a lazy way to splice them.  More logical is a pigtail; but a novice switch replacer usually does not have the supply of wire,  wire-nuts and stripper needed to do a pigtail.

But the #1 complication is dumbth; people not being conscious that they have outranged their skills and thinking they can just blunder about and get lucky. It's less of a risk on switches, but on other things, experientation can lead to many combinations that work *but kill you later*.  Skills are so easy to acquire that I advise to do so.